# C# Compare two ulong lists and subtract extraneous ulong's from the unprotected one

Tags: c#, list

I have two lists of Ulongs:

The first list is a list of ulongs , the second is a (larger) list of ulongs that should be protected.

I want to somehow compare the two lists, and remove any ulongs that the first list has that the protected list does not have (sort of garbage collection I guess).

What would be the recommended way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are after is intersection.

```
var source = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
var protectedSet = Enumerable.Range(9, 4);
var result = protectedSet.Intersect(source);
```

Which would result in:

source:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

protectedSet:

```
9
10
11
12
```

result intersection:

```
9
10
```

Comment: I ended up using except instead of intersection, which gave me the differences between the protected set and the old set. With those differences (keys), i pruned my data set to keep it up to date and keep the size down. :)